# React Native Forms Handling on Submit Button

Tags: react-native, react-forms

I am new to React Native. I am building an app where there is a contact form in it. I want to collect all the forms field data and want to send these details entered by the users to a specific email on clicking Submit button.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure if you can send email directly from react native app directly.

You can try using [react-native-email](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-email) package. Its quite easy to integrate. The package uses Linking API

```
import email from 'react-native-email'//imports the package

handleEmail = () => {//function to send email
    const to = ['tiaan@email.com', 'foo@bar.com'] // string or array of email addresses
    email(to, {
        // Optional additional arguments
        cc: ['bazzy@moo.com', 'doooo@daaa.com'], // string or array of email addresses
        bcc: 'mee@mee.com', // string or array of email addresses
        subject: 'Show how to use',
        body: 'Some body right here'
    }).catch(console.error)
}
```

}